# Update all rows affected by a group by

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sql-update

I have the following query using PostgreSql :

```
SELECT SUM(table.a) 
FROM table 
GROUP BY table.b
HAVING SUM(table.a) > x;
```

And now I need to update a column in all rows affected by the precedent query.

I tried the following solution :

```
UPDATE table 
SET c = 'value' 
WHERE (SELECT SUM(table.a) 
       FROM table 
       GROUP BY table.b) > x;
```

but I get the following error

> More than a line returned by a sub-request used as an expression

I cannot find a solution to update a column in all rows affected by a group by. If anyone can show me the way, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please post your error in English?

Comment: sorry, I edited my post

Comment: Please also tag the database engine you’re using, they all have differences in their syntax and it helps to know which one to target

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to update table rows only for those rows that have table.b in the list of values of those whose sums of *table.a* column values exceeded your defined *x*

So, I believe you want to use this:

```
UPDATE TABLE
   SET c = 'value'
 WHERE b IN (SELECT b
               FROM TABLE
              GROUP BY table.b
             HAVING SUM (table.a) > x));
```

Comment: You could simplify this by just returning b from the innermost query and dropping the middle one

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen You're absolutely right! Thank you for your input :)